# Is there any way to use a webview to load a html page over a network?

Tags: android

So I am pretty new to android programming and need to turn a preexisting log in system currently embedded into a basic program into an android one. Basically its just a number of files over the network that are embedded and the files do all the work. Unfortunately at the moment I don't have access to the files so I can't store them locally and use them in the webview that way. I couldn't really find another case like this, so I was hoping someone with more experience could either point me in the right direction or help me out a bit. I may have left some stuff out so if anyone needs additional information, feel free to ask. Thanks in advance.